# Use apply() on a 1-dim vector to find the best threshold

Tags: r, apply, na, data-cleaning

My current mission: pick up some "good" columns from a incomplete matrix, trying to remove NAs  while keeping real data.

My idea: I can calculate evey column's missing data `NA%`. For a given threshold `t`, all the `NA% > t` columns will be removed. The removed columns also contain some real data. In these columns, `present/missing` will show the "price" of deleting these columes. My idea is to search the lowest "price" to delete NA as much as possible, for each dataset.

I already wrote my function till the last 2 steps:

```
myfunc1 <- function(x){
  return(sum(is.na(x))
}
myfunc2 <- function(x){
  return (round(myfunc1(x) / length(x),4))
}
myfunc3 <- function(t, set){
  m <- which(apply(set, MARGIN = 2, myfunc2) > t)
  missed <- sum(is.na(set[m]))
  present <- sum(!is.na(set[m]))
  return(present/ missed)
}

myfunc3(0.5, setA)    # worked
threshold <- seq(from = 0, to = 0.95, by = 0.5)
apply(X = threshold, MARGIN = 1, FUN = myfunc3, set = setA)     # not worked. stuck here.
```

I have 10 datasets from `setA` to `setJ`, I want to test all thresholds from 0 to 0.95. I want a matrix as a return with 10 datasets as column and 20 rows threshold with every 0.05 interval.

Did I do this correctly? Are there better ideas, or already existing libraries that I could use?

----------edit: example-----------

```
setA <- data.frame(cbind(c(1,2,3,4,NA,6,7,NA), c(1,2,NA,4,5,NA,NA,8),c(1,2,3,4,5,6,NA,8), c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),c(NA,NA,NA,4,NA,6,NA,NA)))
colnames(setA) <- sprintf("col%s", seq(1:5))
rownames(setA) <- sprintf("sample%s", seq(1:8))
View(setA)

myfunc1 <- function(x){
  return(sum(is.na(x)))
}
myfunc2 <- function(x){
  return (round(myfunc1(x) / length(x),4))
}
myfunc3 <- function(t, set){
  m <- which(apply(set, MARGIN = 2, myfunc2) > t)
  missed <- sum(is.na(set[m]))
  present <- sum(!is.na(set[m]))
  return(present/ missed)
}
```

In setA, there are 8 samples. Each sample has 5 attributes to describe the sample. Unfortunately, some data are missing. I need to delete some column with too many NAs. First, let me calculate every column's `NA%` .

```
> apply(setA, MARGIN = 2, myfunc2)
 col1  col2  col3  col4  col5 
0.250 0.375 0.125 0.000 0.750
```

If I set the threshold `t = 0.3`, that means col2, col5 are considered too many NAs and need to be deleted, others are acceptable. If I delete the 2 columns, I also delete some real data. (I deleted 7 real data and 9 NAs, 7/9 = 0.78. This means I sacrifice 0.78 real data when I delete 1 NA)

```
> myfunc3(0.3, setA)
[1] 0.7777778
```

I want to try every threshold's result and then decide.

```
threshold <- seq(from = 0, to = 0.9, by = 0.1)
apply(X= threshold, MARGIN = 1, FUN = myfunc3, set = setA)      # not work
```

I manualy calculate setA part:

```
threshold:  0  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6  0.7  0.8  0.9
price:  1.667 1.667 1.118 0.778 0.334 0.334 0.334 0.334 NaN NaN
```

At last I want a talbe like:

```
threshold:  0  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6  0.7  0.8  0.9
setA:   1.667 1.667 1.118 0.778 0.334 0.334 0.334 0.334 NaN NaN
setB:
setC:
...
setJ:
```

Do I have the correct way with the problem?

-----------Edit---------------

I already solved the problem and please close the thread.

Comment: `myfunc3` calls itself recursively and you have not defined `myfunc4`. Is the posted code correct? And what is `setA`, can you post a sample?

Comment: Instead of the the last `apply`, use `sapply` without `MARGIN`, just the rest: `sapply(threshold, myfunc4, set = setA)`.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: sorry, that is a typo. I edited a sample. Thank you very much for reply.